# Constructing URL dynamically in Python

Tags: python, url, flickr

I have an URL template of the form

```
https://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{photo-id}_{secret}.jpg
```

I have retrieved the following fields and there around 1000000 of these records. After retrieving the record below

```
farm-id: 1
server-id: 2
photo-id: 1418878
secret: 1e92283336
size: m
```

I need to construct this URL

```
https://farm1.staticflickr.com/2/1418878_1e92283336_m.jpg
```

I am thinking of some approaches, should I construct a dictionary for this one?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `str.format(*args, **kwargs)`:

```
fmt = 'https://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{photo-id}_{secret}.jpg'
values = { 'farm-id': '1', 'server-id': 2, 'photo-id': '1418878', 'secret': '1e92283336', 'size': 'm' }
fmt.format(**values)
```

Everything surrounded with `{` and `}` in format string is called "replacement field". It ca be used with `kwargs` for such formatting. More info [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Comment: Thankyou Ivan. I started by using dictionaries. This information about kwargs is something new I learnt. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary would probably be your best bet. As an alternative, check out [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

```
Data = namedtuple('farm-id', 'server-id', 'photo-id', 'secret', 'size')
d = Data(1 ,2 ,1418878, 1e92283336, m)
```

Comment: Thanks Josh, yes I did start with a dictionary. I have to traverse through a huge file first extracting the farmids, serverids etc and then construct a url for each of them and I started by storing them into a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to extract the data from the file and now I have two things, a fixed set of keys and a list of different values.

keys

['farm-id', 'server-id', 'photo-id', 'secret', 'originalformat', 'originalsecret']

values

['3', '2287', '2109698205', '20fbbcc947', 'jpg', '7a57411545']

['3', '2063', '2172469872', '8ddb85aedd', 'jpg', 'e12b952909']

['2', '1079', '830593398', '9ddca27ab0', 'jpg', 'bb91586e56']

['3', '2371', '2226919732', '248f23c5ff', 'jpg', '29f35fb0ca']

['2', '1014', '798067744', '4f043d2ea6', 'jpg', 'd739cc870b']

Is there a smarter way of merging these two lists into a dictionary after which I can use the formatting required to create the url

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if your data is in the format you indicated you should make sure that numbers such as `1e92283336` can be interpreted are not interpreted in different way than you intended. For example with `json`

```
>>> json.loads('{"secret" : 1e92283336, "server_id" : 2, "farm_id": 1, "size" : "m"}')
{u'secret': inf, u'farm_id': 1, u'server_id': 2, u'size': u'm'}
```

After you successfully imported the fields to a dictionary there are multiple ways you can use string interpolation and formatting. Apart from the `str.format` specifier mentioned in previous answer you can use the traditional `%` style formatting as below (note the format specifier `s` after the closing parentheses)

```
>>> url = "https://farm%(farm-id)s.staticflickr.com/%(server-id)s/%(photo-id)s_%(secret)s.jpg"
>>> print url % {'secret': '1e92283336', 'server-id': '2', 'farm-id': '1', 'size': 'm', 'photo-id' : '1418878'}
https://farm1.staticflickr.com/2/1418878_1e92283336.jpg
```

You can also use [Template Strings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#template-strings) which uses the `Template` class from the `string` module. This would be more familiar to bash/perl programmers. The template string is of the form below. The placeholders (within optional braces) must be valid python [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers) so it cannot contain characters such as `-`. The first non-identifier character terminates the placeholder. With `safe_substitute` method if any placeholder value is missing it will put the original placeholder instead of raising a key error.

```
>>> from string import Template
>>> s = Template("https://farm${farm_id}.staticflickr.com/${server_id}/${photo_id}_${secret}.jpg")
>>> s.substitute({'secret': '1e92283336', 'server_id': '2', 'farm_id': '1', 'size': 'm', 'photo_id' : '1418878'})
'https://farm1.staticflickr.com/2/1418878_1e92283336.jpg'
>>> s.safe_substitute({'server_id': '2', 'farm_id': '1', 'size': 'm', 'photo_id' : '1418878'})
'https://farm1.staticflickr.com/2/1418878_${secret}.jpg'
```